# SRGS and RecognizeWithUIAsync() on Hololens

Tags: speech, hololens, srgs

I am right now writing an Applikation for the Microsoft Hololens with Visual Studio 2017. Goal is having a speech recognion using speech recognition grammar specification.

I tried my Solution on a Laptop and it works well, but somehow it doesnt with the Hololens Emulator.
The problem is the most basic as it can be. The words aren't recognized. There is no problem with compliling, neither with finding the grxml file. 
Secondly, the RecognizeWithUIAsync() windows doesnt pop up.

C#:

```
        // Create an instance of SpeechRecognizer
        var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(language);

        // Load Grammar depending on the selected language
        var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Grammar/grammatik_de.grxml"));
        var grammarFileConstraint = new SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint(storageFile, "grammatik");


            storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Grammar/grammatik_eng.grxml"));
            grammarFileConstraint = new SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint(storageFile, "grammatik");

            speechRecognizer.UIOptions.ExampleText = @"Example: Stop all vehicles,Fork higher,Fork lower,Vehicle Forward,Drive Backwards";


        // Compile the constraint.
        await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

        // Start recognition.
        SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync(); 

       //do something with the result
        try
        {
            String action = grammarHandling(speechRecognitionResult);
            actionOnSpeechAsync(action);
        }
        catch (Exception) { 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned usage of SRGS, but would the use of `Speech Input Handler` and `Speech Input Source` scripts, built into Mixed Reality Toolkit, help you with your application? I have used it a lot and never seemed to have any problems. It's also easy to debug it.

Regards

Comment: It could! Do you have a link for me? I built the software with Visual Studio so i dont want to use Speech for Holos, instead it should be a command tool for  autonomic transport vehicles. Thank you very much!

Comment: I haven't found any good tutorials on how to use those scripts, but they are quite simple to handle. For my project I created an empty GameObject which I called `SpeechManager`. Inside I added two scripts, mentioned above. In `Speach Input Source` you add your keywords, and in `Input Speech Handler` you set what is to happen when the keyword is said.

Comment: The point of SRGS is to expand the possible input scenarios. For Example you can implement and SRGS logic which understands Please give me a big Hamburger with 200 ML of Coke. You dont need Unity. I just use Visual Studio so therefore no explicit objects are needed. I tried using listConstraints and this worked but the task is to complex to code each possible sentence. Do you got my problem? I think we misunderstood each other

Comment: Oh, got you now..
Sorry for confusion :)